# How does the extraction operator ">>" know when to stop extraction?

Tags: c++, string, input, stream, stringstream

The question is the same as the title, when using the extraction operator ">>" for the string
`"   Hello   World"` There are 3 leading whitespace characters, and after "Hello" there are whitespace aswell, after the word "World" its the end of the string, so my question is how does the extraction operator know if its a preceding whitespace, non-preceding whitespace and if it is the end of the string ?

How is "end of the string" represented concretely, how do we know that in a low level ?

When reading cppreference for the operator "std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::operator>>"
The following is shown:
[image: cppreference]

Since our operand here is a basic_istream (im not sure) it corresponds to the 17th description which says "Calls func(*this), where func is an I/O manipulator." what does this mean ? How should i interpret this ?

```
istringstream ss(s); 

string word;

while(ss>>word)
  {
   // do something
  }
```

Comment: Obviously how this happens is implementation specific, but for example, the stringstream object could store an integer representing the current position in the string being read. If that integer is equal to the overall size of the string then you know you have reached the end. In practice I imagine similar code would be implemented with pointers or iterators but the idea is the same.

Comment: None of the overloads from the reference you are quoting apply, because your second argument is a string. You need to look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) to find the overload (which is #2). The overloads you are looking at are all defined in `<istream>` but the extraction operator for strings is defined in `<string>` so it's on a different page.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, the link you provided answers my questions.

Comment: In actual fact all stream objects delgate the I/O operations to *stream buffer* objects. For `std::istringstream` that object is of type `std::stringbuf`, and that's the object that holds the string being read and knows where the end of the string is.

Comment: its is not overload (17). That overload is for iomanipulators which are functions (with signature `basic_istream& (basic_istream&)`). What you are looking at is member functions, hence the left hand side operator is not explicit on the meber function signature, its the current object, `this`. `ss >> word` is `ss.operator<<(word)`

Comment: on the same page, scroll down to find a link to this one https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt. This overload is not a member, hence you see the stream and the string as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really anything complicated, the basic algorithm is described on cppreference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt

A basic implementation (with no doubt plenty of bugs and missing features) would look something like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::istream& read(std::istream& is, std::string& str)
{
    while (std::isspace(is.peek()))
    {
        is.get();
    }
    str.erase();
    while (is)
    {
        auto c = is.peek();
        if (c == std::char_traits<char>::eof() || std::isspace(c))
        {
            break;
        }
        str.append(1, is.get());
    }
    return is;
}

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss("   Hello   World");
    std::string word;
    while (read(ss, word))
    {
        std::cout << "'" << word << "'\n";
    }
}
```